# div overlaps on another div when screen size reduced

Tags: html, css

Below is a simple html web page that is responsive except for one div (goplay) that over lays other parts of the page when screen size is reduced, instead of dropping below the image.

Styling Sheet external

```
 #wrapperlp {
        width: 100%;
        margin: auto;

    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
        #wrapperlp {
            width: 90%;
            min-width: 100px;
        }
    }

    #headerlp {
        font-size: 30px;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }

    #para {
        font-size: 20px;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #game_img {
        height: 250px;
        width: auto;
        margin-bottom: -30px;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        margin-top:-30px;
        padding-top: 5px;
        max-width: 100%;
    }

    #goplay {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        float: right;
    margin-top:-250px;
        margin-left:80px
    }
    #spacer {            
        height: 40px;           
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 900px;
    padding-top:20px;
    }
```

Html which is set to call the above css

```
<div id="wrapperlp">
<div style="background-image: url(https://.jpg); height: 430px; width: 1000px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; max-width: 100%;">
<div id="headerlp">Some Text</div>
<div id="para">More Text</div>
<div id="game_img"><a href="//www.youtube.com/" target="_blank"><br />
                <img src="https://.png" height="auto"/></a></div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="goplay">----form----/div>
<div id="spacer">
<div style="position: relative; float: left">Text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

margin-top and left should in %. thats y its overlay becoz of px

Answer (score 0):

First off, it looks like you're missing a couple of divs.
The goplay div doesn't have a closing tag, (well it's got one but not that works)
Also your bottom spacer looks like it's missing a closing tag as well.  Not sure if it's supposed to wrap anything or what.

Perhaps you had some copy/paste errors?

Normally if you set a negative margin it will overwrite other divs.  You should, for the most part, not have to use negative margins.